# why can't I use my webcam on site using a flashplayer?

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, flash

How can I resolve this issue even using VMware/Virtual Machine on windows I cant access my camera using a flashplayer even on google chrome whats the problem?. I just encounter this problem after I install linux live on my laptop completely erase all windows inside the hard drive

Comment: Does the webcam work with any other application? Have you tried using `cheese`?

Comment: [Ubuntu App Directory entry for *Cheese*](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cheese/); includes a link for installation with Software Center.

Comment: yes sorry for the late response , Cheese is working fine on my machine however if a site uses sa flash it cannot determine if I have a webcam on my machine